# how to use path.basename with bjam?

Tags: bjam, b2

I am currently using this action:

```
actions re2c {
  re2c --tags -o `basename $(<)` $(>)
}
```

But I'd like to use the `path.basename` rule instead. Something along the lines:

```
rule re2c ( targets * : sources * : properties * )
{
  import path ;
  targets = [ path.basename $(targets) ] ;
}
```

This approach is not working for me.